# Total angle within a closed surface...

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

So I know that the degrees of a triangle add up to 180 degrees.  This seems to make sense, on some intuitive level.

Now, if you have a closed object constructed of four lines (perhaps most simply a square), the angles add up to 360 degrees.

What if you have five lines?

Should there not be some function $ F( $ **[** number of lines forming closed surface **]** $)=$ **[** Sum of the angles between them **]** ?

Can someone be so kind as to prove this function using any method?

(It feels hallow to say I know these things without being able to prove them!)

Answer (score 1):

Very true! There is such a function. If you have convex $n$-gon, then the sum of its interior angles is $(180n-360)^{\circ}$. To prove this just triangulate the $n$-gon like the following:
[image]

Sum of angles for each triangle add upto $180^{\circ}$, and sum of all those angles add upto sum of all interior angles of the $n$-gon. (Note that a $n$-gon can be triangulated into $n-2$ triangles).

From this we can also imply a very interesting fact that: Whatever be $n$ th sum of the external angles of a convex $n$-gon always add upto $360^{\circ}$.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of analysis I was thinking of using to find it, actually...